# Concate string in asp.net with jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to concatenate the block of asp.net with jquery in block of jquery code :

```
 var srcImg = "<%:HelperClass.CheckImageUrlExist(HelperClass.Project.PathBrandImages+ "+ 
 proValByDep.brNam + ")%>";
```

proValByDep.brNam is the variable in my jquery.

Could anyone help me, how could I can concatenate this string?

Comment: you need to somehow let the server know (via hidden field or so) about `proValByDep.brNam`

Comment: Do you mean, I have to assign `proValByDep.brName`  to the value of some hidden field or so, and then calling to use by asp.net?

Answer (score 1):

The question in its current state will not work.  You cannot have the ASP.NET runtime try to resolve the client-side javascript variable before your html is recieved by the client.